# Use Variable value in a SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i have declared a variable @S and i am storing a sub query value in it which is returning more than one record , now what i want is to use it in a select statement , can i do that is it possible,

here is my query what i was trying but getting an error Must declare the scalar variable "@S"

```
Declare @S AS NVarchar(MAX)
    SET @S = '(SELECT es.FirstName FROM [User] es  WHERE  es.UserId IN (SELECT CustomerUserID FROM OrderInfo))'

SELECT  
        OrderInfoId,
        BorrowerFirstName As ConsumerFirstName,
        BorrowerLastName As ConsumerLastName,
        RequestedURL,
        Requests,
        SELECT @S,
        u.FirstName +'' ''+ u.LastName As Affiliate,
        o.RequestDateTime As DateOfTransaction,
        o.RequestIPAddress As OriginatingIPAddress, 
        o.Requests As Status
from orderInfo o 
inner join [User] u on o.AffiliateId = u.UserId
```

is it possible to do that. any help will be appreciated

Comment: What exactly are you expecting that query to return?

Comment: Your query will fail if your sub query returns more than 1 value anyway which looks highly probable judging by the query

Comment: unrelational to what you ask but .try to remove `select` before `@S` . you are selecting twice in query.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to append *as a single string* the result of the sub-query to every row produced by the main query, then, first of all you have to initialize `@S`:

```
Declare @S AS NVarchar(MAX) = ''
```

then properly set it:

```
SELECT @S = @S + ' ' + es.FirstName 
FROM [User] es  
WHERE  es.UserId IN (SELECT CustomerUserID FROM OrderInfo)
```

and finally consume its contents in the main query:

```
SELECT  
        OrderInfoId,
        BorrowerFirstName As ConsumerFirstName,
        BorrowerLastName As ConsumerLastName,
        RequestedURL,
        Requests,
        (SELECT @S),
        u.FirstName +'' ''+ u.LastName As Affiliate,
        o.RequestDateTime As DateOfTransaction,
        o.RequestIPAddress As OriginatingIPAddress, 
        o.Requests As Status
from orderInfo o 
inner join [User] u on o.AffiliateId = u.UserId
```

Answer (score 2):

Your biggest issue is that you're trying to select multiple rows into a single column.  This can't be done.  You will need to concatenate the FirstNames into a single value.  There are a few ways to do this.  One popular way is to use `STUFF` with `FOR XML` This is an example of how you would get all of the FirstNames that match your sub query into a column.  The names will be comma separated.

```
SELECT
    OrderInfoId,
    BorrowerFirstName AS ConsumerFirstName,
    BorrowerLastName AS ConsumerLastName,
    RequestedURL,
    Requests,
    STUFF((SELECT
            ', ' + es.FirstName
           FROM
            [User] es
           WHERE
            es.UserId IN (SELECT
                            CustomerUserID
                          FROM
                            OrderInfo)
           ORDER BY
            es.FirstName
          FOR
           XML PATH('')
          ),1,2,'') AS CustomerFirstNames,
    u.FirstName + ' ' + u.LastName AS Affiliate,
    o.RequestDateTime AS DateOfTransaction,
    o.RequestIPAddress AS OriginatingIPAddress,
    o.Requests AS Status
FROM
    orderInfo o
    INNER JOIN [User] u ON o.AffiliateId = u.UserId
```

This seems a little strange too considering you're going to get ALL user first names that have a CustomerID in orderInfo.  You might want to filter your sub query by orderInfo.Id or something.

Are you sure you're not just trying to get the CustomerID first name? You can join to [User] again to get this information.

```
SELECT
    OrderInfoId,
    BorrowerFirstName AS ConsumerFirstName,
    BorrowerLastName AS ConsumerLastName,
    RequestedURL,
    Requests,
    cu.FirstName AS Customer,
    u.FirstName + ' ' + u.LastName AS Affiliate,
    o.RequestDateTime AS DateOfTransaction,
    o.RequestIPAddress AS OriginatingIPAddress,
    o.Requests AS Status
FROM
    orderInfo o
    INNER JOIN [User] u ON o.AffiliateId = u.UserId
    INNER JOIN [User] cu ON o.CustomerUserID = cu.UserId
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to make the entire sql statement a string, and use sp_executesql like so:

```
DECLARE @OrderID int;
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@SubQuery varchar(255), '+
                         '@OrderInfoOUT varchar(30) OUTPUT';
SET @S = '(SELECT es.FirstName FROM [User] es  WHERE  es.UserId IN (SELECT CustomerUserID FROM @OrderInfoOUT = OrderInfo))';
SET @SQL ='        OrderInfoId, '+
            'BorrowerFirstName As ConsumerFirstName, '+
            'BorrowerLastName As ConsumerLastName, '+
            'RequestedURL, '+
            'Requests, '+
             @SubQuery+', '+
            'u.FirstName +''' '''+ u.LastName As Affiliate, '+
            'o.RequestDateTime As DateOfTransaction, '+
            'o.RequestIPAddress As OriginatingIPAddress, '+
            'o.Requests As Status'+
    'from orderInfo o '+
    'inner join [User] u on o.AffiliateId = u.UserId';

sp_executesql @SQL, @ParmDefinition,  @SubQuery=@S, @OrderIDOUT=OrderID OUTPUT;
```

Then you can store the results in variables as I've show with OrderInfoOUT

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to run it this way.  You would need something like [sp_executesql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a mix of concepts in your question: dynamic SQL with table variables.

If you're using SQL Server 2008 or uper, you have a choice to create table variables that keep alives for the period the hosting routine is running. 
You can define something similar to this:

```
DECLARE @UserInfo TABLE
( 
    FirstName varchar(50) NOT NULL
);
```

Load the information as follows:

```
INSERT @UserInfo
SELECT es.FirstName 
FROM [User] es  
WHERE  es.UserId IN (SELECT CustomerUserID FROM OrderInfo)
```

Finally you can join table variables similar as temporal tables based on your needs.